# Javascript not working in external file

Tags: javascript

I'm trying some JS basics for a little test and have encountered with a problem when trying to put the Javascript code outside of the HTML one.

The HTML:

```
<body id="index" class="home">
<table style="width:100%">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Region</th>
    <th>Population 2012</th>
    <th>Population 2035</th>
    <th>Annual Growth</th>
    <th>Daily Growth</th>
    <th>Incr./Sec</th>
    <th>Live Pop</th>
    <th>GDP p/c annual</th>
    <th>GDP p/c month</th>
    <th>Incr./Sec</th>
    <th>GDP 2012</th>
    <th>GDP 2013</th>
    <th>Area</th>
    <th>Land</th>
    <th>Water</th>
    <th>Density</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
<th>EU</th>
<td>503 492 041</td>
<td>520 654 000</td>
<td>746 172</td>
<td>2 044</td>
<td>0.02366</td>
<td><label id="populationEU">503604514.99676</label></td>
<td>31 959.42 €</td>
<td>2 663.29 €</td>
<td><label id="GDPEUIncrement">0.00101</label> €</td>
<td>16 091 315 618 944.38 €</td>
<td><label id="GDPEU">2 425 518 867 456.69</label> €</td>
<td>4 324 782.00 km<sup>2</sup></td>
<td>4 191 578.71 km<sup>2</sup></td>
<td>133 203.29 km<sup>2</sup></td>
<td>116.42 hab/ km<sup>2</sup></td>
</tr>
<h1 id="test"></h1>
<hr />
<tr>
<th>Asia</th>
<td>4 227 067 000</td>
<td>6 534 959 649</td>
<td>84 541 340</td>
<td>231 620</td>
<td><label id="populationAsiaIncrement">2.6808</label></td>
<td><label id="populationAsia">4239810309.5035</label></td>
<td>4 629.42 €</td>
<td>385.79 €</td>
<td><label id="GDPAsiaIncrement">0.00016</label> €</td>
<td>19 568 885 419 408.00 €</td>
<td><label id="GDPAsia">3 120 792 273 016.10</label> €</td>
<td>44 579 000.00 km<sup>2</sup></td>
<td>43 286 209.00 km<sup>2</sup></td>
<td>1 292 791.00 km<sup>2</sup></td>
<td>94.82 hab/ km<sup>2</sup></td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/counters.js"></script>
</body>
```

And the JS:

```
var test = document.getElementById("test"); // Test placeholder

var millennium =new Date(2013, 0, 1); //Month is 0-11 in JavaScript
var today=new Date();
var one_day=60*60*24; //Get 1 day in seconds

//Calculate difference btw the two dates, and convert to days
var secondsSinceNewYear = Math.ceil(today.getTime()-millennium.getTime());

var populationEU = document.getElementById("populationEU");
var totalPopEU = 0;
var incrementEU = 1/2 ;

setInterval(popGrowthEU, 500);

function popGrowthEU()
{
totalPopEU = totalPopEU+incrementEU;
populationEU.innerHTML = addCommas(Math.round(totalPopEU*100)/100);
}

var GDPEU = document.getElementById("GDPEU");
var totalGDPEU = 0;
var incrementGDPEU = 1*totalPopEU/10;

setInterval(GDPGrowthEU, 100);

    function GDPGrowthEU()
    {
        totalGDPEU = totalGDPEU+incrementGDPEU;
        GDPEU.innerHTML = addCommas(Math.round(totalGDPEU*100)/100);
    }

var populationAsia = document.getElementById("populationAsia");
var incrementPopAsia = parseFloat(document.getElementById("populationAsiaIncrement").innerHTML);
var totalPopAsia = populationAsia.innerHTML+(incrementPopAsia*secondsSinceNewYear);
var incrementPopAsia = incrementPopAsia/2;
setInterval(popGrowthAsia, 500);

function popGrowthAsia()
    {
        totalPopAsia = totalPopAsia+incrementPopAsia;
        populationAsia.innerHTML = addCommas(Math.round(totalPopAsia*100)/100);
    }

var GDPAsia = document.getElementById("GDPAsia");
var incrementGDPAsia = document.getElementById("GDPAsiaIncrement").innerHTML;
var totalGDPAsia = incrementGDPAsia*secondsSinceNewYear*totalPopAsia;
var incrementGDPAsia = incrementGDPAsia*totalPopAsia/10;

setInterval(GDPGrowthAsia, 100);

function GDPGrowthAsia()
{
totalGDPAsia = totalGDPAsia+incrementGDPAsia;
GDPAsia.innerHTML = addCommas(Math.round(totalGDPAsia*100)/100);
}

function addCommas(nStr) {
nStr += '';
var x = nStr.split('.');
var x1 = x[0];
var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ' ' + '$2');
}
return x1 + x2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9GTFS/

I have some data, for now the initial data it's hardcoded, and  though i try to update certain fields (the ones with a "label" tag and id) in certain intervals using JS. When i do It putting the JS code in the HTML page, it works perfectly fine, but when I take it out and put it in a separate file it doesn't work. Actually, i managed to figure out that the line

`var incrementPopAsia = parseFloat(document.getElementById("populationAsiaIncrement").innerHTML);`

finds the problem that the label with that information (id 'populationAsiaIncrement') returns an "undefined" state and I'm stuck there, because I think everything's right. What could be causing this issue?
I think it's not a DOM issue because the JS is loaded at the very end of the page, so every bit of code has been loaded (and so all the DOM elements the javascript needs) and, in fact, the element that's failing (label id="populationAsiaIncrement") actually exists.

The specific problem that ends up showing is that `document.getElementById("populationAsiaIncrement").innerHTML` for some reason doesn't get assigned to the variable. If I execute just that in Firebug, it shows me the expected value, but when I try to assign it to a variable it gets "undefined".

Comment: Paste your code here, in addition to providing the Fiddle link.  Fiddle goes dead, question goes dead.

Comment: you don't need a `<body>` tag in your HTML for jsfiddle.

Comment: I think it's not a DOM issue because the JS is loaded at the very end of the page, so every bit of code has been loaded (and so all the DOM elements the javascript needs) and, in fact, the element that's failing (label id="populationAsiaIncrement") actually exists.

Comment: @Ikzer you should have posted the actual code from your real site, not the jsfiddle. The jsfiddle page you posted is configured to run your JavaScript in a "load" handler. If you put your importing `<script>` tag in exactly the same place as your in-line `<script>`, it will work the same.

Comment: You should definitely close your `<script>` tag for one... you can't rely on autoclosing script tags. In my tests if you don't close your script it wont even execute.. I don't know if this is the full issue though as it doesn't make sense that you'd get an error half way down your script.

Comment: I did It and It doesn't work. In Firebug I get an "undefined" as response on that line. The label with the id "populationAsiaIncrement" exists, have valid data, but still the JS file gets an "undefined". If I replace that document.getElementById with an integer, the code works, so the problem is there and I can't find it.

Comment: You are performing arithmetic on strings (i.e, concatenation versus addition).   You need some parseInt's in your logic to perform type conversion.

Comment: That's not the problem, I had tried It and doesn't work. The problem is tat for some reason the value of that getElementById isn't assigned to the variable, it just keeps on getting an "undefined".

Comment: var totalPopAsia = parseInt(populationAsia.innerHtml,10)+(...) causes your fiddle to work under both Chrome and FireFox.  If you don't do this then the result (of your subsequent operation on the totalPopAsia string) is NaN.

Answer (score 4):

Put the `<script>` tag with which you import your JavaScript at the very **end** of the `<body>` instead of in the `<head>`.

Imported scripts are evaluated as soon as the browser gets them, synchronously. If you put a script in the `<head>` and it tries to find DOM elements, they won't exist because the body of the document hasn't been parsed yet. By putting the script at the end, you avoid that problem.

*edit* — in your jsfiddle, the code works because that site by default wraps your JavaScript code up inside a function that's set up as a "load" handler for the page.  It won't run until after the page has loaded. That's another option for you too, but you'll have to structure the code that way yourself.

Comment: Isn't the same thing true for embedded scripts?

Comment: @Barmar well you do have a point :-)  In the fiddle, however, it works because jsfiddle is putting the code in a "load" handler.

Comment: But he says it's also working in his regular site. So if he loads the external JS at the same place where he had the embedded script, it should work.

Comment: @Barmar it's not clear to me that there actually is a "regular site", but you may be right. One way or the other, however, JavaScript in the `<head>` simply will not see DOM elements in the `<body>`. That's why I concluded that the "regular site" is just that jsfiddle. I understand that I'm guessing :-)

Comment: He said _When i do It putting the JS code in the HTML page, it works perfectly fine_ and I interpreted that to mean embedding the JS in his regular HTML file, not the fiddle.

Comment: @Barmar yes, but since it's absolutely impossible that it actually worked if that code were in the `<head>` before the `<body>`, I interpreted that statement loosely. Again, you may be right, but if so then there are things the OP isn't telling us.

Comment: He's posted the code, the `<script>` tag is at the end of the `<body>`.