# Javascript beginner.. how do I get this code to work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My question relates to the following code:

Currently I have the JS code within the HTML, and it works fine.

How do I place it in the scripts folder and call it through HTML?

I have tried various ways and it won't work, as in the JS will not function unless its in the HTML how it is right now.

Please help!

HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow-wrapper clearfix">
       <img class ="myPics" src="images/puppy.jpg">
       <img class="myPics" src="images/paw.jpg">
       <img class="myPics" src="images/donkey.jpg">
       <img class="myPics" src="images/bunny.jpg">
       <img class="myPics" src="images/kittens.jpg">
    </div> <!-- End of slideshow-wrapper div -->
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
 var myIndex = 0;
 carousel();

 function carousel() {
 var i;
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myPics");
     for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
         x[i].style.display = "none";
     }
 myIndex++;
 if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
 x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
 setTimeout(carousel, 1000); // Change image every 2 seconds
 }
```

I have tried the following:

```
<script src="./scripts/carousel.js"></script>
```

the JS file looks like this:

```
<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myPics");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
}
myIndex++;
if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
   x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
   setTimeout(carousel, 1000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

The file is called carousel.js

It will not function while in the separate file

Comment: What "scripts folder"?  How are you currently including this code in the page and how is it failing?  The `<script>` tag implies that this is included directly in the HTML itself, is that true?  Please provide a more complete example of the problem.

Comment: You know the way you would have folders for css , images, scripts ?

Comment: I could help for a few cheap upvotes, but I suggest you Google javascript basics and read some tutorials, or even look at the source of some sites, you will learn more.

Comment: @Maria: I know the way *I* would have my code organized, but how do *you* have *your code* organized?  It's important that you specify an actual problem, not a theoretical description of a problem.

Comment: I have googled it for hours and cannot get it to work

Comment: I have it currently as I stated, the script is actually in the HTML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript not working in external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100708/javascript-not-working-in-external-file)

Comment: I still can't get it working..

Answer (score 2):

Include this line in your html file. 
myscript.js is your javascript file, you can write here the path starting from where the html file is located

```
 <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
 <html>

 </html>
```

Comment: that part is fine, but how do I call the js for the images?

Comment: @Maria the js doesn't care about (has no references to) the images only the tags `id=myPics`